# Help with HTML/CSS to make a two-column and background setup

Tags: css

Hi I would like to replicate the setup. I'm currently trying to use a div for the yellow background and inside it two nested divs for the purple blocks of text. If I don't put any additional elements in the outer div the background color doesn't appear. If I put an element, just to test, I get the yellow border between the purple blocks not around them.

edit: updated the link to a working image.

http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/5yxlv3hQEcS5GN-VXomD0w?feat=directlink

Comment: please provide some sample code, the link isn't working

Comment: This is the code I'm trying to use:

<style>

.caja {
margin: 3em;
background-color: #FFEC40;
}

.caja-izquierda {
float: left;
width: 45%;

background-color: #FF52C2;
color: white;
}

.caja-derecha{

float: right;
width: 45%;

background-color: #FF52C2;
color: black;
}

</style>

<div class="caja">
<div class='caja-izquierda'>
<p>Mis actividades:
<ul>
<li>Calestenia</li>
<li>Palestra</li>
<li>Dise&#241o Web</li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>

<div class='caja-derecha'>
<p> Miss intereses son:
<ul> 
<li>tecnologia</li>
<li> la agricultura </li>
<li> Propaganda </li>
</ul>
</p>
</p>
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
min-height:Value;
```

on the outer element to force it to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I am also unable to visit your link.

Check out 960 CSS Framework. It is an excellent way to quickly and easily create multi-column layouts.